# Do I have to specify a mapping in order to use the document.search controller in Kuzzle?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, sdk, kuzzle

I am using Kuzzle in order to build a simple slack-like application. I have a simple collection with documents only containing other documents ids.
I wanted to query a list of ids from this collection and got stuck with an empty hits array in the response, no matter what id values I tried in the query. It got me to read about Elasticsearch query syntax, mapping, and I found out I needed to specify a mapping.

When the collection is created without specifying a mapping, document.search:

- returns an empty array of hits if given a "query" body property such as the following:

  ```
  {"query": {"terms": {"id": <ids array>}}}
  ```
- throws the following if given a "sort":

  ```
  // {"sort": [{"id": {"order": "desc"}}]}
  Error: No mapping found for [id] in order to sort on
  ```
- and returns an empty bucket list for an "aggregations" like this :

  ```
  "aggregations": {
      "groupById": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "id"
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I don't understand what is happening behind this. Is it normal that only one case is being treated as an error? I was working on the query part, and it was not obvious that the error didn't come from the content of my ids array!

Adding a simple mapping on "id" with the "keyword" type makes all cases work as intended, but I read about dynamic mappings in Elasticsearch. Is there a way to use them? Or is there another solution for querying a (the only) parameter in my document?

I'm using kuzzle-sdk v7.1.4

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch mappings are a way to tell the underlying engine how to index the fields of your documents.

For example, a [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) field will not be indexed the same way as a [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) field and you won't be able to make the same kind of query.

`keyword` fields are indexed "as is", so you can do very fast search on exact terms (with the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)) but `text` fields are analyzed with various method to be able to do a [fuzzy match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) for example.

If there is no declared mapping for a field, Elasticsearch won't be able to access it in any query.

You can read our [Elasticsearch Cookbook](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/cookbooks/elasticsearch/basic-queries/) for more informations.

About the [mappings dynamic policy](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/essentials/database-mappings/#dynamic-mapping-policy), by default this policy is set to `false`, meaning that ES will not infer newly introduced fields types.

We choose to have this default value because you cannot modify the type of a field so it's better to define it yourself than having poorly accurate types inferred by ES.

You can change this policy for the entire mapping but also for only a nested object for example (which is considered as a best practice)

```
{
  "dynamic": "false",
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "keyword" },
     "metadata": {
       "dynamic": "true",
       "properties": {
         // field types will be automatically inferred in the "metadata" object
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Then if you create the following document:

```
{
  "id": "your-unique-uuid",
  "name": "aschen",
  "metadata": {
    "avatar": "http://url.com"
  }
}
```

- `id` field was already declared as `keyword`, you can make query
  on this field.
- `name` field was not declared and the dynamic policy is `false`
  so you cannot make query on this field.
- `metadata.avatar` field was not declared but the dynamic policy
  for this nested object is `true` so ES will add a `text` type for
  this field, you can make query on this field.

One last thing, you are using an `id` field inside your document but Elasticsearch already generate unique identifier (`_id`) for every documents so you may want to use this instead.

*I am a developer on Kuzzle core*

Comment: Thanks! Missed the mappings dynamic policy :') One last thing, is it expected behavior that my query does not throw an error when searching for the 'id' field without having provided a mapping, but instead returns an empty hits array?

Comment: Yes, this is Elasticsearch default behavior. But if you try to sort on this field you will get an error I think